# How can I make my Ubuntu 12.04 auto-shutdown when battery is fully charged?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, battery, automatic

I would love if someone could give me a script or something like that to make it do what I describe in the title...

Comment: ... any reason why? seems a little dramatic if you are using your laptop and it shutdown because the battery is now full instead of empty!

Comment: Is your goal to fully charge your device while minimizing electrical usage without having to check battery status regularly?

Comment: Also, please note that your laptop will charge even when turned off (assuming it's plugged in and its battery hasn't been removed). In fact, it will probably charge faster when turned off than when turned on, since none of the power it's getting has to go to actually running the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small python program which uses terminal to look into file for battery status and handles the operation with defined function. This will work for general case, but though, there might be a little problem. It uses the package "`acpi`" which monitors the battery status. The program is:

```
import commands
import pynotify
from threading import Timer


def battery_check():

    rem = float(commands.getoutput("grep \"^remaining capacity\" /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state | awk '{ print $3 }'"))
    full = float(commands.getoutput("grep \"^last full capacity\" /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info | awk '{ print $4 }'"))
    state = commands.getoutput("grep \"^charging state\" /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state | awk '{ print $3 }'")

    percentage = int((rem/full) * 100)

    if percentage == 100:
        pynotify.init("Battery Full! Now shutting down")
        os.system("sudo shutdown now -h -k") //shutdown command issued

    timer = Timer(300.0,battery_check)
    timer.start()

if __name__ == "__main__": battery_check()
```

Comment: This script looks reasonable to me.  Note that the script will need to be run as root, e.g. `sudo python ./battery.py` (assuming the script is called `battery.py` and is located in the current dir).